# Implement react routing in html page from json

Tags: reactjs, innerhtml, react-router-dom

I have some issue in implementing routing as expected. 
My scenario here is I have a component, content inside the component is get from the json data in server. In the content there are some `<a>` tags, when I click on the link, page is reloading instead of how actual routing works.

what I have tried is

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
............. other imports ....
const htmlContent=`<div> 
                     <p> Lorem ipsum content goes here </p>
                      <a href="/home">Home</a>
                    </div>`;
export class InnerPage extends Component{
 ...... other stuffs .......
 render(){
    return(
      <div>
          // static content
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlContent}} />

      </div>
     )
  }
}
```

Here it renders the html content as expected, but the routing is not working as expected. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` instead of a regular anchor.

Comment: @GaëlS I am adding inner html from json. If i am using jsx its possible. I am using pure html here